# how use labels plugin in doughnut in Es module

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I use chartjs in my project and I need to display data on Doughnut.
So, I install the plugin of datalabels

```
import { Chart , registerables } from 'chart.js';
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

Chart.register(...registerables, ChartDataLabels)
```

But it doesn't work by adding the plugin in register, Igave the following error

```
 Uncaught Error: Dynamic require of "chart.js/helpers" is not supported
    at chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js:7:9
    at chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js:8:89
    at node_modules/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js (chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js:11:1)
    at __require2 (chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js:10:50)
    at chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js:1356:3
(anonyme) @ chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js:7
(anonyme) @ chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js:8
node_modules/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js @ chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js:11
__require2 @ chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js:10
(anonyme) @ chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js:1356
```

Any idea, how can I fix this problem, please